# Rally App SDK 2.0: Exit Policy Not Available in Custom Kanban Board

Tags: javascript, rally

It seems that the Exit Policy fields are not available in custom kanban boards that utilize the Rally code as a base? It seems that it is checking the value for the following:

```
this._isToggledOn('PORTFOLIO_ITEM_KANBAN_POLICIES')
```

However, even though the check seems to return true, and the "Show Policies" checkbox is added, the exit policies are not rendered correctly when it is checked.